# Ajax Function when search results page has same field ID names

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am working on a script that prints an HTML table from an SQL table, based on results of a search. The table will print a button if the value of a particular field is not 1. So, in different search results, there could be various buttons printed on the table. When you press the button, the value of that field should update to 1 via AJAX call.

Here's the PHP code for printing the table:

```
echo "<title>Search Results</title>";
     if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo '<table style=\"width:100%\"><tr>
            <th class="text-left">Name</th>
        <th class="text-left">Paper 1 Signed?</th>
        <th class="text-left">Paper 2 Signed?</th>
        <th class="text-left">Paper 3 Signed?</th>
            </tr><br>';
      while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                      $ID         = $results['ID'];
                      $Name       = $results['Name'];
                      $paper1     = $results['paper1'];
                      $paper2     = $results['paper2'];
                      $paper3     = $results['paper3'];

            echo '<tr>', //print the first column
          '<td class="text-left">',$Name,'</td>'

   //print the 3 remaining columns, depending on their values in the SQL table. If 1, show text. If not 1, print a submit button.

          if ($question1 == '1') {echo "<td class=\"text-left\">Signed!</td>";}
          else {echo "<form id=\"update\" method=\"POST\" action=\"\" ><td class=\"text-left\">
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"field_update\" value=\"paper1\"/>
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"ID\" value=\"" . $ID . "\"/>
          <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"saveData()\" value=\"Mark as Signed\"></form></td>" ;} // 

          if ($paper2 == '1') {echo "<td class=\"text-left\">Signed!</td>";}
          else {echo "<form id=\"update\" method=\"POST\" action=\"\" ><td class=\"text-left\">
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"field_update\" value=\"paper2\"/>
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"ID\" value=\"" . $ID . "\"/>
          <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"saveData()\" value=\"Mark as Signed\"></form></td>" ;}

          if ($paper3 == '1') {echo "<td class=\"text-left\">Signed!</td>";}
          else {echo "<form id=\"update\" method=\"POST\" action=\"\" ><td class=\"text-left\">
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"field_update\" value=\"paper3\"/>
          <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"ID\" value=\"" . $ID . "\"/>
          <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"saveData()\" value=\"Mark as Signed\"></form></td>" ;}

            echo "</tr>" ;
             ;   
   } 
   echo '</tbody></table></body></html>';  
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing found';
    }
```

Note the last three sections: this is where I print the last 3 columns of the table, showing if paper 1, paper 2 and paper 3 have been signed. If yes (=1), then I show the text "Signed!" If no (!=1), then I print an update button.

The update (submit) button is connected to a saveData() onclick function written in JQuery/AJAX.

```
<!-- function update -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveData(){
        var field_update = document.getElementById("field_update").value; 
        var ID = document.getElementById("ID").value;
        var dataString = 'field_update=' + field_update + '&ID=' + ID;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update-ajax.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success:function( html ) {
           alert( html );

          }
         });
    }
```

My issue is the following: the var values in the function are always going to the first row of values... this is because the field IDs for each column element in the table are the same.. so the function is always using the first set of results.

I could possibly run a loop to print a different javascript function for every row and cell... BUT that would be very inefficient.

I know there must be a better way, but scratching my head here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's me but I didn't get what is your issue exactly and what is happening here

Comment: The problem is: IDs have to be document-widely unique by specs.

Comment: @HrvojeGolcic my issue is that my javascript function points to two static field names (field_update and ID).. which doesn't work for me because I am printing various fields as it is a search result page. So I'm trying to understand the best way to update the function or my printing of fields in order to allow it to work properly (my objective would be that clicking the button in a particular table row and column will send the correct 2 values to the jquery function)

Comment: The easiest could be giving elements, e.g. the corresponding submit buttons, class names. Then select them by `$('.class-name')` or `getElementsByClassName` in pure JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why its taking the first row values is because the ids you are using are not unique. Since you are using jquery, you could do something like this.

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click',function() {

});
```

This will attach this callback function to all submit button in the page. Now to know what values to use within the callback function, I suggest you use jQuery's `data()` function and `data-*` attributes. Something like this.

```
      "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"saveData()\" value=\"Mark as Signed\" data-id=\". $ID. \"></form></td>" ;}
```

Note the `data-id=$ID` bit. Now you can access this id within the callback function using

```
$(this).data('id')
```

which will automatically get you the value of data-id attribute. No need of unique ids and jumping through hoops!

Comment: interesting. but, I have 2 different data fields that I need to submit. not just 1. it looks like in your example, only the ID datapoint is included.

Comment: You can have any number of data-* attributes. Simply add `data-field="paper1"` and you can access `$(this).data('field');` to get the field_update that you are using within the callback. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: OK, thank you. So how would I update this line in the function in order to point to the 'this' part you mentioned, assuming I placed field_update value as data-field in the input? var field_update = document.getElementById("field_update").value;

Comment: Bind the event to the `td` element and select the `input` element in the subtree. `$(this).find('input')`

Comment: Place the data-* attributes right on the submit button. $(this) will point to the submit button since the click is bound to the button.

Comment: Using classes could make things easier.

Comment: so in my savedata function, I would update the variable to be "field_update = $(this).data('update');" ? assuming that I added another attribute data-update in the submit button?

Comment: Awesome. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your id with an 'a_', 'b_', and 'c_' and you can easily split the javascript string to get the right id in your AJAX call.

As for unsolicited advice, learn a templating system, it will make your code much less difficult to read.

Comment: yes but even if I have a_, b_, c_ for each column, the field names are still the same for each row.. and the function is taking the first row field names. That is my problem.